# Alternatives to Fano's Axiom in Projective Space

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, axioms

In Projective Geometry, Fano's Axiom says:

> The three diagonal points of a complete quadrangle are never collinear.

I would like to *prove* this from more basic Axioms within three-dimensional Projective Space. The theorem of Desargues is non-trivial in *plane geometry*, but can be proven from basic axioms within *three-dimensional geometry*; could the same be true for Fano's Axiom? If not, are there nice (equivalent) alternatives?

Edit: by “more basic” I mean intuitively more basic, which makes it a somewhat subjective question of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove Fano's axiom from 3-dimensional geometry because the projective plane over the field $F_2$ with two elements does not satisfy Fano's axioms.  Recall that the projective plane can be defined starting with 3-dimensional space over $F_2$ by a suitable equivalence relation.

Comment: I admit that the formulation of my question was not quite clear. What I meant to ask is: could Fano's axiom be replaced by (i.e. proven from) intuitively more basic axioms in three-dimensional space? So in particular spaces over $F_2$ would be excluded by these axioms.

Comment: Yes, the axiom is that the characteristic of the field has to be different from 2.

Comment: I was hoping for somewhat more synthetic axioms – similar to Fano's Axiom, but more elementary.

Comment: The existence of a betweenness relation (a la Hilbert) is probably enough to guarantee this (though this needs to be checked) but that would be a much stronger condition.